# Format XML String - EDOMParseError

Tags: xml, delphi

I want to format a xml-string like it's done in notepad++.

The problem when using FormatXMLData ( the solution provided https://stackoverflow.com/a/235901/3135176 ) I get a parse error on the namespaceprefixes.

sample xml string :

```
<ns1:Make><ns1:CustomerID>K||15538</ns1:CustomerID></ns1:Make>
```

result in notepad++ :

```
<ns1:Make>
    <ns1:CustomerID>K||15538</ns1:CustomerID>
</ns1:Make>
```

Please advice

Answer (score 4):

Your sample string does not declare the namespaces you are using, so you get the parsing error.

FormatXMLDoc is for formatting documents, not snippets.

Put a breakpoint on `FormatXMLDoc()` and step into it (compile with debug DCUs).  You will see that the first thing it does is create a document from your string.  So it needs to be a complete and valid document.